# Android startActivityForResult within TabActivity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

I searched for my specific question and I couldn't find an answer of my problem.

On my app, my main activity has a tab host with 3 tabs. All three tabs have a list view with items.

The tab1 list view items are related to both tab 2 and tab 3 list view's items. One item on tab1 can correspond to one or more on tab 2 or 3.

Now the tricky thing:
When I click one item on each tab, I start a new activity to edit or even remove that item. After this action  I need to change the listViews on all tabs, not only the inner activity tabbed that called for the action. The same is to say  I need to refresh at least two tab activities (therefor the main activity). 
I can start the editing Activity with a startActivityForResult() and get the result of the action and update the current activity/tab). Now the problem is, I can't pass to the main activity any information to refresh the whole content. I thought about starting the main activity with data, when I update the contents but then it starts a new one, and when the user clicks to exit the app there's one (or more, depending on the number of actions perfomed) main activity on the background.

How can I update the main activity? How do I signal the main activity from inside an activity called on a tabbed activity?
If I only needed to refresh the inner tab, there would be no problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tabs area actually activities and only one is visible at a time what you can do is to ise the on Resume method which is called when the new activity becomes visible you update it. Also you can use ontabchangedlistener.